# how to run sql file(having multiple queries and comments) from gradle script on teamcity agent

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, gradle

I want to run oracle sql file (createdb.sql) which is in my linux teamcity agent at location /home/tools/sabaDB. I have tried exec like

> ```
>             exec { commandLine "sqlplus", "/nolog", "@createdb.sql"
>                             workingDir "home/tools/sabaDB"}
> ```

Its working when I run it from linux agent but not through teamcity I trigger gradle build script Its showing like error=2, No such file or directory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B74Xm.png)

I have checked file and oracle_home is properly set ( its running from my agent)
so basic question is 
how to create gradle task which will run whole sql file having  ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have to specify  environment that will pass environment variables to teamcity environment like

`exec { env key="oracle_home" path="oracle/home/path"
commandLine "sqlplus", "/nolog", "@createdb.sql" workingDir "home/tools/sabaDB"}`

and it worked